# Sending and getting http headers

Tags: asp.net, authentication, asp.net-web-api, http-headers, asp.net-authorization

I am working on an asp.net Web API and I have an web application that consumes this api.
Right now it is working perfectly since I don't have the [Authorize] part on my api controller.
So, if I want to secure this api, my web application will not be able anymore to fetch data from the API because it is not authorized.
So how can I send the token generated from my API to my web app and to allow it to fetch the needed data?
-I am using postman for testing my app;
-my api return jwt token;
-I am not really familiar with http headers.

My consuming web application controller :

```
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            IEnumerable<OperatorClass> OperatorObject = null;
            HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
            client.BaseAddress = new Uri("https://localhost:44304/api/");
            var ApiOpController = client.GetAsync("data");
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Authorization", "Bearer"+"");
            ApiOpController.Wait();
            var resultDisplay = ApiOpController.Result;
            if (resultDisplay.IsSuccessStatusCode)
            {
                var readTable = resultDisplay.Content.ReadAsAsync<IList<OperatorClass>>();
                readTable.Wait();
                OperatorObject = readTable.Result;

            }
            else
            {
                OperatorObject = Enumerable.Empty<OperatorClass>();
                ModelState.AddModelError(String.Empty, "No records found");
            }
            return View(OperatorObject);
        }
```

My web API controller

```
[Authorize]
[HttpGet]
public IHttpActionResult GetOperators()
{
    SchoolEntity myEntity = new SchoolEntity ();
    IList<OperatorClass> OperatorObject = myEntity.Operator.Include("Operator").Select(x => new OperatorClass()
    {
        name = x.name,
        lastname = x.lastname,
        mobile = x.mobile,
        username = x.username,
        password = x.password
    }).ToList<OperatorClass>();
    return Ok(OperatorObject);
}
```

Comment: Please include more information about you chosen method of authentication. How are you generating the JWT?

Comment: I am using Owin host,security.cors for generating the JWT. It is all good with that, I can easily generate a token after a successful login but now I want to use that token for my web application to authorize it and let it get the data from my api.

Comment: What version of net are you using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
string token = <Your token>
client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Authorization", $"Bearer {token}");
```

this should work for you.

To be able to use your MVC controller, you need to store the token when it returns.
One way to do it is to store it using **Session**.

Assuming you are using sign in to get the token, anytime you sign in successfully you can store the token using the session. See below.

```
//For brevity after successful login
string myToken = <token returned from api>
HttpContext.Session.SetString("token", myToken);
//other codes
```

then you can use this in all of your controllers.

```
public async Task<ActionResult> Index()
        {
            IEnumerable<OperatorClass> OperatorObject = null;
            HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
            client.BaseAddress = new Uri("https://localhost:44304/api/");
            
            //note here
            var token = HttpContext.Session.GetString("token");
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Authorization", $"Bearer {token}");
            //ApiOpController.Wait();
            var resultDisplay = await client.GetAsync("data");
            if (resultDisplay.IsSuccessStatusCode)
            {
                var readTable = await resultDisplay.Content.ReadAsAsync<IList<OperatorClass>>();
                //readTable.Wait();
                OperatorObject = readTable;

            }
            else
            {
                OperatorObject = Enumerable.Empty<OperatorClass>();
                ModelState.AddModelError(String.Empty, "No records found");
            }
            return View(OperatorObject);
        }
```

Comment: I tried it with the first piece of code you sent but it is not working. I get the logic that the api/"server" should send it to the app/"client" as a confirmation response but I am all new to web api's and http headers so I'm stuck here. Is there any other method I can achieve this? I read somewhere that this can be done with cookies/headers/sessions but none of them really worked with my code.

Comment: I see that you are sending the request before adding the Authorization Header.

Comment: Yes maybe, because it returns empty list, which normally after authorizing with a token it should be full of data. Where should I add the header or what should I do, pls help me.

Comment: omg it finally worked. I just had to remove the *"http.context.getString("token")* part because it caused me some error and just left the token="" and then i pasted my token there and now it is working. Thank you so much for your time and your help, much appreciated.

Comment: Hi @Taryosky, what if I want my token to get set dynamically by API and not statically as we setting it now? Because the token can expire in some days and it's not forever usable this way and it is not very efficient... is there any way we can take it directly from api via headers or...